# URL Hacking using custom button to populate a custom look up on Case

Tags: urlhacking

I did Url Hackinig several times.
But this requirement is a bit different to me.
The field that I need to populate is read only field to the Users.
Being a admin I can look at the Lookup field Id which is stored on custom setting.

```
{!$Setup.FieldIDs__c.S_OPTY__c}_lkid='+ optyrecords[0].Id.
```

Did some one know how to get access to the field that is read only. In this situation.

Thanks,
Suree.

Comment: Without Visualforce, you can't. The field is read only, meaning the database would not accept any value other than the default.

Comment: Are you saying you want to look up the hard-coded ID from a custom setting, in order to include that ID in a URL hack on a custom button?

Comment: The field is read only at page layout level. Just because of that it is a lookup field and when I click the mirror image I get a popup and I am refering to the lkid in the URL . it is working for sys Admins as they have access to this field but not to the users.